# Is it possible to bind a `NSTextfield` to only one particular entry in a NSArray or NSSet/ Relationship

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

Is it possible to bind a `NSTextfield` to only one particular entry in a NSArray or NSSet/ Relationship.

I can see the possibility of binding to an `NSArrayController` using the `Control Key` of `filterPredicate` but what would be the `Model Key Path`?

Further, can a single NSArrayController have many filterPredicates either methods or properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot bind to a specific object in a set because there is no way to consistently express a given object within the set. The only method for extracting an object from a set is `anyObject`. For arrays its another matter. They can be indexed them and the bindings API allows you to do this:

```
// Edit: changed the code to use bindings directly instead of KVO

[_textFild bind:NSValueBinding 
       toObject:array[indexToBindTo]
    withKeyPath:@"firstName"
        options:nil];
```

You can't do this directly in Interface Builder so it has to be done in code.

Comment: i thought it possible to bind to a specific object in a set using a predicate, such as "name like xxxx". but how to model key path. or perhaps im way off. maybe an additional controller that has the predicate set in fetchPredicate.

Comment: If you fetch the objects yourself then by all means you can just add the binding programmatically but KVC does not support predicates in the key path (key paths are not the same as predicates).

Comment: so perhaps the question is poorly phrased. there is a "filterPredicate" choice in ControlKey. Does that choice even require a ModelKeyPath. Of can one simply call it alone. It seems that Cocoa bindings uses the property name, say "firstName". Surely it would be possible to provide a method body for "firstName" that basically fetches using a predicate. At any rate, cheers

Comment: You probably see "filterPredicate" because you are binding to an array controller, which has a fiterPredicate property. You can use this property to filter the content of the array controller but that will affect everything that is bound to that controller. I have modified the above code sample to give you an alternative way of implementing what I think you are looking for.

Comment: aha. yes. "filterPredicate" is used in a Search box and indeed that does affect everything bound to a controller. Which is not desired in this particular case. im assumming that the indexToBindTo might be a fixed value like '0'. But might be possible to get the selectionIndex from another Controller. cool. thanks for the help.